# Detect phone call using CallKit while in background

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to detect when the user gets a phone call. I have tried the following:

```
import CallKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIApplicationDelegate {
   
    var callObserver: CXCallObserver!
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    callObserver = CXCallObserver()
    callObserver.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: CXCallObserverDelegate {
    func callObserver(_ callObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {
    if call.hasEnded == true {
        print("Disconnected")
    }
    if call.isOutgoing == true && call.hasConnected == false {
        print("Dialing")
    }
    if call.isOutgoing == false && call.hasConnected == false && call.hasEnded == false {
        print("Incoming")
    }

    if call.hasConnected == true && call.hasEnded == false {
        print("Connected")
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine while the app is in the foreground. But it's not quite working while the app is in the background.

This is the first time I am trying to execute codes from the background. This is the approach I took right now. Am I doing it right?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your app cannot detect calls if it isn't in the foreground.

Comment: @Paulw11 that's a bummer

Comment: @Paulw11 but doesn't TrueCaller do this?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. True caller register a callkit number block extension and provides a list of numbers for the system to block.